# Convergence and Divergence and Using Various Methods

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I am totally confused with the idea of convergence and divergence and which method to use to proof it.

An example is a question like this:

---

> Does this integral converge? $$\int_{12}^\infty x^{-x}\mathsf dx $$

Another question is

> Does this integral converge?
>     $$\int_1^\infty \left(\frac{\sin x}x\right)^2\mathsf dx$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I know the various theorems such as squeeze, integral, p-test but just need a bit of help.

Comment: Here's some help on how to make the math more readable. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Do you know Abel-Dirichlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hints:

$$\int_{12}^\infty \frac{1}{x^x}\, dx \le \int_{12}^\infty \frac{1}{x^{12}}\,dx.$$

When thinking about $\int_1^\infty (\sin^2x/x^2)\,dx,$ what is the simplest bound on $\sin^2 x$ you can think of?

Comment: Okay right, so in essence if i can find the simplest bound of sin2xsin2⁡x than I can use the comparison test or intergral test?

Comment: Why do say sin 2x sin 2x? Yes of course we are using the comparison test.